# Using VBScript to create a line and change line color in powerpoint slide

Tags: vbscript

I want to use VBScript to create a line and change line color into black in powerpoint slide. just sample code is fine. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you've already tried/done? SO isn't a "write your code for you" site.

Answer (score 0):

I recorded typing a line then changing it's colour. This is the VBA code.

```
    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Rectangle 3").Select
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=0).Select
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
        .Text = "Hi There" + Chr$(CharCode:=13)
        With .Font
            .NameAscii = "Arial"
            .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
            .Size = 32
            .Bold = msoFalse
            .Italic = msoFalse
            .Underline = msoFalse
            .Shadow = msoFalse
            .Emboss = msoFalse
            .BaselineOffset = 0
            .AutoRotateNumbers = msoFalse
            .Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
        End With
    End With
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor = ppAccent2
```

Which can be condensed to

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Rectangle 3").Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=0).Select
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
    .Text = "Hi There" + Chr$(CharCode:=13)
    With .Font
        .Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
    End With
End With
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor = ppAccent2
```

Then to convert it to typeless and use late binding. Also convert named parameters to positional. Replace constants with their values (looked up in Powerpoint's object browser). Be aware the application object isn't global so put `pp.` in front of methods and properties.

```
Set PP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Rectangle 3").Select
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1, 0).Select
With pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
    .Text = "Hi There" + Chr$(13)
    With .Font
        .Color.SchemeColor = 2
    End With
End With
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor = 2
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor = 7
```

The above is both valid VBScript and VBA.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's useful for text setting,  but I need a sample code for creating a black line in a powerpoint slide, or creating a retangle with black frame and transparent interior. Look forward to your further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I showed you how to convert VBA's recording syntax to standard VBA/VBScript.

Record your actions and PowerPoint will do it for you.

Alt + T, M, R (and same keys to stop recording). Press Alt + F11 to see the recorded code. Then convert as above.

This is powerpoint recording drawing a line.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro recorded 15/08/2016 by User
'

    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddLine(59.5, 219#, 671.88, 219#).Select
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        .Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = ppForeground
        .Line.Visible = msoTrue
    End With
End Sub
```

So replace constants with their values. Add a app object using `createobject` as in the above post.